# Inelastic collision problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

A car of mass  $1400$ $\mathrm{kg}$    moving  south  at  $11$  $\mathrm{ms}^{−1}$  collides  into  another  car  of  mass  $1800$ $\mathrm{kg}$  moving  east  at  $30$ $\mathrm{ms}^{−1}$.  The  cars  are  stuck  together  after  the  collision.  Determine  the velocity  of  the  cars  immediately  after  the  collision.

I know the problem can be easily solved by conservation of momentum before and after collision. But I get confused in the direction in which the system will move after collision. I have solved many problem but I make a mistake every time. I have taken this very basic problem to understand the concept properly. Please throw some insight so that I can get a clear picture of after collision every time without making a mistake.

Comment: You don't really need to know the direction......just use $m_1u_1+m_2v_2=(m1+m2)v'$...the direction can however be obtained by writing down momentum and KE equations, and solving them for v.

Answer (score 3):

The way to approach this problem is to use the vector momenta and conserve them. If we orient our coordinate axis such that our $x$-coordinate is pointing North and our $y$-coordinate is pointing East, then the momentum of the first car is:

$$\vec{p}_{1}=m_{1}\vec{v}_{1} = 1400\begin{pmatrix}-11 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}\:\text{kg m s}^{-1}$$

Similarly, the momentum of the second car is:

$$\vec{p}_{2} = m_{2}\vec{v}_{2} = 1800\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 30\end{pmatrix}\:\text{kg m s}^{-1}$$

Conservation of momentum means that:

$$\vec{p}_{\text{final}} = \vec{p}_{1} + \vec{p}_{2} = \begin{pmatrix}-15400 \\ 54000\end{pmatrix}\:\text{kg m s}^{-1}$$

But $\vec{p}_{\text{final}} = (m_{1} + m_{2})\vec{v}_{\text{final}}$ and so we can find the velocity of the cars after the collision:

$$\vec{v}_{\text{final}} = \frac{1}{1400+1800}\begin{pmatrix}-15400 \\ 54000\end{pmatrix}\:\text{m s}^{-1} = \frac{1}{16}\begin{pmatrix}-77 \\ 270\end{pmatrix}\:\text{m s}^{-1} \approx \begin{pmatrix}-4.8 \\ 16.9\end{pmatrix}\:\text{m s}^{-1}$$

So the joint cars are travelling east at approximately $16.9\:\text{m s}^{-1}$ and south at approximately $4.8\:\text{m s}^{-1}$.

Comment: I think the final velocity should be calculated only after finding the direction in which the system will move after collision. You haven't used vector here.

Comment: @user109256 Finding the final velocity is equivalent to finding the direction in which the system will move after collision. What do you mean I haven't used vectors?

Comment: I mean you haven't visualized the direction in the system will move after collision. Considering cars as particles and then colliding and visualizing the final direction of the system on paper.

Comment: @user109256 one doesn't need to draw arrows to correctly calculate vectors in Cartesian coordinates.